# 'requiredMessage' attribute not working in xhtml form. Error message won't display

Tags: validation, xhtml, ajax4jsf

I have the following code:

```
Enter a word:
<h:inputText value="#{testfile1.input}" styleClass="textbox" id="inputID" maxlength="100" required="true" requiredMessage="Input should not be blank">
        </h:inputText>
<h:message for="inputID" style="color:red"/>
<a4j:commandButton value="Save" styleClass="button" action="#{testfile1.saveData}"> </a4j:commandButton>
```

The save button doesn't work if the above field is left blank, which is exactly what i want. But i am unable to display any error message.

Comment: You can use `h:commandButton` if you want submit form with checking all fields. You can use `a4j:commandButton` with attribute `immediate="true"` and field checking will be skipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your commandButton is not re-rendering the h:message

you can wrap the h:message like so to auto-render whenever an ajax request is made...

```
<a4j:outputPanel ajaxRendered="true">
    <h:message for="inputID" style="color:red" />
</a4j:outputPanel>
```

or...used the rendered attribute on the commandButton (eg. render="@form")